# Moving the public folder outside the project laravel

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, directory

I want to move `public` folder outside of my project in laravel

```
-->|-Project
   |  |___app
   |  |___bootstrap
   |  |___....
   |-public
```

I have moved directory folder then an error occurs said

```
   Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException 

  The provided cwd "C:\xampp\htdocs\site\ProjectNamexx\public" does not exist.
```

So I have create just empty folder called public, just to bypass error;
And in `bootstrap` directory, I have specified that folder `public` which become now in parent foder by this `dirname(getcwd(), 1)` and old code was `dirname(__DIR__)`

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);
$app->usePublicPath($app->basePath("public"));
```

But The **ERROR:** occured

```
In RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php line 43:

  RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(): Argument #1 ($directory) cannot be empty
```

I have tried to solve it by just hardcoded the url and not worked as well, please if you already had this issue, or you have any idea how to solve this problem, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Edit `public/index.php`

```php
require __DIR__.'/../Project/vendor/autoload.php';

if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../Project/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../Project/bootstrap/app.php';
```

2. Edit `bootstrap/app.php`. Add before return $app;

```php
$app->bind('path.public', function () {
    return base_path() . '/../public';
});
```

3. Create `Project/.htaccess`. if you're webhosting

```php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```